# Spring amqp stop endless retrying loop, if rabbitmq service is not working

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm having trouble with stopping infinite retrying when rabbitmq server is down. I tried using this code snippet

```java
@Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    BackOff recoveryBackOff = new FixedBackOff(5000, 1);
    factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
    return factory;
}
```

But I am still getting endless loop of retrying

```
17:49:47,417 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#13-1]     Starting consumer Consumer@4f35699: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 WARN o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]      stopping container - restart recovery attempts exhausted
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]     Shutting down Rabbit listener container
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 INFO o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#13-1]    Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 INFO o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]      Waiting for workers to finish.
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 INFO o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]      Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]     Cancelling Consumer@e56de36: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2020-08-31 17:49:49,431 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#34-2]      Closing Rabbit Channel: null
2020-08-31 17:49:51,434 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#13-1]     Recovering consumer in 5000 ms.
2020-08-31 17:49:51,434 DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [main]     Starting Rabbit listener container.
2020-08-31 17:49:51,434 INFO o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory [main]    Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 17:49:53,485 INFO o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [main]      Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2020-08-31 17:49:53,485 INFO o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#35-1]    Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 17:49:55,518 ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#35-1]     Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
```

What I am trying to achieve, is that after one attempt of connecting, stop trying

**Edit 1**

I have my whole consumer side config here, I can't seem to find where another configurable container factory could be. The thing is, if I have fixed back off at for example 3000 ms, the message changes to `Recovering consumer in 3000 ms.`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        jsonObjectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(jsonObjectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitErrorHandler rabbitExceptionHandler() {
        return new RabbitErrorHandler();
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        BackOff recoveryBackOff = new FixedBackOff(5000, 1);
        factory.setRecoveryBackOff(recoveryBackOff);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I'm using version 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and it worked as expected:

```
2020-08-31 11:58:08.997  INFO 94891 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 11:58:09.002  INFO 94891 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-08-31 11:58:09.006  INFO 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 11:58:09.014  INFO 94891 --- [           main] com.example.demo.So63673274Application   : Started So63673274Application in 0.929 seconds (JVM running for 1.39)
2020-08-31 11:58:14.091  WARN 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-08-31 11:58:14.093  INFO 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@6f2cb653: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2020-08-31 11:58:14.094  INFO 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-08-31 11:58:14.095  WARN 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : stopping container - restart recovery attempts exhausted
2020-08-31 11:58:14.095  INFO 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2020-08-31 11:58:14.096  INFO 94891 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

I see you have

```
 stopping container - restart recovery attempts exhausted
```

too.

Perhaps the listener that keeps trying is from a different container factory?

```
Recovering consumer in 5000 ms.
```